# How do I restart iPad with broken power button and unresponsive screen?

Tags: ios, touchscreen, ipad

My iPad 4 running iOS 8.0.x suddenly stopped responding *only* when in apps.  On the home screen taps and gestures work fine.

When I tap any app icon the app launches but doesn't respond to any touches or gestures.  This happens to both Apple apps (Settings, etc.) and third-party apps.

The iPad still responds to system gestures though, like four-finger pinch to go to the home screen.

I'm guessing a restart will fix this, but the power button is broken and the iPad is on a full charge.  Is there any other way to force a restart?

Comment: Upgrading to iOS 8.1 will cause it to restart. :P (It may also resolve your other issues.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### If you have AssistiveTouch enabled

You can use all the physical features on your device (volume control, on/off button, etc.)

Tap on the dot that appears on your screen. On the popup, tap "Device". Press and hold "Lock Screen", then slide to power off.

Depending on what is causing your device's power button not to work, you may or may not be able to turn it on now in the traditional way by pressing and holding the power button. If that fails, connect your device using its USB cord either to a computer or to a wall socket, and it should turn on after several seconds.
Once the iPad turns on you can enable AssistiveTouch by going to Settings > General > Accessibility > AssistiveTouch (under "Interaction"), and swipe the switch to turn on AssistiveTouch.

AssistiveTouch is an accessibility feature designed for people with limited movement capacities.  For more information about AssistiveTouch, see [this Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT5587).

### If AssistiveTouch is not enabled

You will just have to wait for the battery charge to run out.

Comment: This worked because I already had Assistive Touch enabled.  But if not I wouldn't have been able to enable it because even the Settings app was unresponsive.