# What do I do to start my iPad back up if it is powered off and power button doesn't work?

Tags: ipad

My iPad is powered off and I can't get on it because the power button doesn't work. Is there an alternative way to turn it on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restart iPad with broken power button and unresponsive screen?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155445/how-do-i-restart-ipad-with-broken-power-button-and-unresponsive-screen)

Answer (score 1):

These things will resolve all issues:

1. Enable Assistive Touch: Settings>General>Accessibility>Assistive Touch
2. This will give you an on screen button, navigate to Device and then hold the sleep/wake on screen button, slide to power off
3. To turn the iPad back on, plug the device into power.

Answer (score 0):

Plug into a PC/Mac, or charge it using your charger which comes with the iPad/iPhone package.